# How to show all combinations of picking 3 balls in a jar of 20 balls and 1 ball in two other jars of 5 balls

Tags: python, numpy, math, combinations, probability

I know how to return the list of all possible combinations of picking 3 balls in a jar of 20 possible balls:

```
list(itertools.combinations(range(1,21),3))
```

But what if I have two balls from two jars ( First I will pick a ball in a jar of 5 balls and do it again in another jar), How can I get the possible list of all combinations?

Comment: sorry i edited it, there are 20 balls in the first jar, 5 balls in the second, 5 balls in the third. You need to pick 3 balls randomly from the first jar, 1 from the 2nd, 1 from the last. I would like to know all the combinations there are in this problem.

Comment: I would like to have the list of all possible combinations.

Comment: Keep reading the `itertools` documentation; there are more methods there for solving your combinatorial problems.

Comment: @user2505650 I take it you are aware that this will be a rather long list?

Comment: yes of course, I  already did it for bigger combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that the balls in your first jar are numbered `1` through `20`, those in your second jar are `31` through `35`, and those in your third jar are `41` through `45`, so we can keep the balls and jars straight. Then you combine the `itertools.combinations` function with `itertools.product` to get a list of all the possibilities:

```
list(product(combinations(range(1,21),3), range(31,36), range(41,46)))
```

This will make a long list, with 28500 items. The first item in the list is

```
((1, 2, 3), 31, 41)
```

meaning balls `1,2,3` from the first jar, ball `31` from the second jar, and `41` from the third jar. The final item is

```
((18, 19, 20), 35, 45)
```

with the obvious meaning. If you just want a tuple of 5 numbers without any inner tuple, such as `(1, 2, 3, 31, 41)`, you could "flatten" the tuples in multiple ways, such as

```
[(*v[0], *v[-2:]) for v in
    product(combinations(range(1,21),3), range(31,36), range(41,46))]
```